# Websphere 8.5 JAX-WS WSDL redirect

Tags: redirect, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws

I got a SOAP web service with code first approach running with the built in JAX-WS implementation in Websphere 6.1.

The service was migrated from Websphere version 6.1 to version 8.5.

Formerly (version 6.1) the WSDL was available directly at the URL
[...]/services/SomeService?wsdl

Since migrating to version 8.5 the WSDL is still available via aforesaid URL, but a redirect is being made to
[...]/services/Services_002f_SomeService.wsdl

A client needs to access the WSDL before each request that is being made to the web service and is not getting on with the redirect (i.e. with the [...]?wsdl-URL), so he needs the redirected URL. (This is something I'm having no bearing on, unfortunately... )
Problem is that the '002f' part in the redirected URL is dynamic and might be changed by Websphere. (It did already in our testing environment.)

Does anybody know an option that prevents Websphere from the aforementioned redirect?

Comment: How the service is defined? Please attach code. Is it in web or ejb module? In my tests redirect is always to `/context-root/HelloService/HelloService.wsdl`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason for the weird '002f' characters in the redirect URL.
It is due to the given serviceName **services/SomeService**

```
    @WebService (targetNamespace="http://example.net/", serviceName="services/SomeService")
```

\u002f is the '/' character in UTF8

So redirect goes to **[...]/services/SomeService/Services_002fSomeService.wsdl** and is reasonable.

The info of a possibly changing redirect URL to ...003f..., ...004f..., etc. which I got is obviously wrong.

Though not redirecting would not have caused any troubles at all and I don't know why the new JAX-WS implementation in WAS 8.5 really has to do that, I' coming to terms with just giving the (as I know know) static '002f' WSDL URL to the client.